# How to jump the unpack directory in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to unpack a .tgz file and jump to the directory released. I know the command in terminal is:

```
tar -xvzf xxx.tgz
```

and then jump to the direcotory:

```
cd xxx
```

But how can I do this in shell script? I don't know how to get the directory the 'tar' command released, can anyone help me?

Comment: Anything you can type in a terminal will work in a shell script, so your script is nothing more than putting those two commands in a file and executing it

Comment: But in terminal I get the directory name manual and 'cd' to it , in script I don't know how to get the directory name.

Comment: The directory name after unpacking tar,gz is same, eg. `xxx.tar.gz` unpacks into `xxx`, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @vish4071 no it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229504/find-extracted-directory-name-from-tar-file):

```
test1=$(tar -axvf something-1.3.5a.tar.gz)
cd $(echo $test1 | cut -f1 -d" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would unarchive `xxx.tgz` and `cd` into whichever directory it extracts into:

```
tar -xvzf xxx.tgz && cd $(tar -tf ${_} | head -1 | cut -d / -f 1)
```

This takes that into account that the directory which the archive is extracted to might not be the same name as the archive. The method extracts the archive then checks it's contents in order to determine where it actually extracts to. There is some level of fragility to be aware of and adjustments might need to take place for unusual filenames.

Here are a couple of other (slightly more generic) examples:

```
mkdir -p xxx && tar -xvzf ${_}.tgz -C ${_%%.tgz}
```

Would create the directory `xxx` and extract `xxx.tgz` in `xxx` even if it normally extracts to `xyz`.

```
tar -xvzf xxx.tgz && cd ${_%%.tgz}
```

Unarchives `xxx.tgz` then uses bash parameter substitution to `cd` into the `xxx` directory.

Comment: This assumes that the tar filename's prefix is the same as the directory that all of the files are extracted so. That is a very common convention, but not guaranteed. Having said that, it will work for a large number of cases, so it may be sufficient for what the requester needs.